# React makeStyles doesn't set background image

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, create-react-app

Despite trying several ways to load the image for the backgroundImage property, it never shows up in page. Loading external images (for example from google) works as expected.

I tried:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${Papyrus})`
backgroundImage: "url(" + Papyrus + ")"
backgroundImage: "url(../../assets/images/papyrus.png)"
backgroundImage: Papyrus
backgroundImage: "url(\"../../assets/images/papyrus.png\")"
backgroundImage: "url(assets/images/papyrus.png)"
```

NONE of them work. The image is loaded when I look at my network audit, I can find it in the static folder, but it's never displayed.

App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import makeStyles from './app-styles';
import {Container} from "@material-ui/core";
import Description from "../description/description";

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const classes = makeStyles();
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Container maxWidth={"xl"}>
                <div className={classes.row}>
                    <Description/>
                </div>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

description.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import makeStyles from './description-styles';

interface DescriptionProps {
}

const Description: React.FC<DescriptionProps> = () => {
    const classes = makeStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.descriptionCard}>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Description;
```

description-styles.tsx

```js
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";
import Papyrus from "../../assets/images/papyrus.png";

export default makeStyles(theme => ({
    descriptionCard: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Papyrus})`,
        // margin: 'auto',
        height: '25vh',
        width: 'calc(20vw * 0.54 - 2%)',
        borderRadius: 8,
        display: 'flex',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        marginTop: '10px'
    },
    text: {

    }
}))
```

Comment: can you console log the url(${Papyrus}) statement?

Comment: @Domino987 I'm not sure how to console log that statement. What exactly do you want me to type?

Comment: export default makeStyles(theme => {
console.log(url(${Papyrus}))
return {
    descriptionCard: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Papyrus})`,
        // margin: 'auto',
        height: '25vh',
        width: 'calc(20vw * 0.54 - 2%)',
        borderRadius: 8,
        display: 'flex',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        marginTop: '10px'
    },
    text: {

    }
}
}))

Comment: You can't console log that due to a parsing error. Are you sure you did that before?

Comment: yes i am sure xD
makeStyles(theme => {
    console.log(url(${ Papyrus }));
    return {
        descriptionCard: {
            backgroundImage: url(${ Papyrus })
        }
    }
});
Are you sure you have copied it right?

Comment: Try adding following properties as well - 
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',

Comment: @MonikaMangal I don't understand why but adding those made it work. If you post it as an answer (with some explanation) I will accept it.

Comment: Great, I will do that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add some additional properties to the background image and it will work -

```
descriptionCard: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Papyrus})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center', 
        backgroundSize: 'cover', 
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        // margin: 'auto',
        height: '25vh',
        width: 'calc(20vw * 0.54 - 2%)',
        borderRadius: 8,
        display: 'flex',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        marginTop: '10px'
    }
```

I'm not sure why we need these additional properties (maybe someone could add to the answer), but sometimes the image needs certain behaviour to be defined, like size, position, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should write it line this:

```
backgroundImage: `url(images/papyrus.png)`
```

And it should work.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Also it's pretty much the same as backgroundImage: "url(../../assets/images/papyrus.png)"

Comment: I updated my code, which works for me. I just tried it out.

Comment: Where is your image located anyway?

Comment: src/assets/images/image

Comment: ok for images,, which are not in the public folder([docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files]), you can just reference them like this:  background-image: url(./papyrus.png);

Comment: your link has an extra %5D at the end

Answer (score 2):

This way works for me

```
    import LaptopImage from "../../assets/laptop.jpg";
    ...

    const useStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        wrapper:{
            backgroundImage: `url(${LaptopImage})`,
            height: '100vh'
        }
    })
```

Its the bare minimum. Rest you can align it properly.

Comment: This works for me, the image file gets loaded here; else the CSS is there but the image file is missing

Answer (score 1):

use props, try this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bg: props => ({
    backgroundImage: \`url(${props.backgroundImage})\`
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing this problem all morning. Here is how I fixed. First, import the image then add it to the string:

```
import banner_background from "./banner_background.png";

backgroundImage: `url(${banner_background})`
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, you can import a picture first, after that use it as a component.

```
import yourPicture from './assets/img/yourPicture.png'
...
const userStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${yourPicture})`,
    minHeight: '100vh', // set height size 100%
  },
})
```